# How to display animated products in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms

**I have a list of 6 products:**

```
<l:WrapLayout x:Name="_data" Spacing="7" UniformColumns="2" Padding="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" x:DataType="model:Product">
                <Frame HasShadow="False" IsClippedToBounds="True" CornerRadius="7" Padding="0" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#f7f7f7">
                    <Image Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding images}"/>
                </Frame>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>                                                                                                                        
</l:WrapLayout>

private List<Product> _listProd;
protected async void LoadProducts()
{
    ......
    var prdGet = ss.ToList();
    _listProd = prdGet;
    BindableLayout.SetItemsSource(_data, _listProd);
}
```

**As in my code above. I display my products in 2 columns and 3 rows.**

It actually displayed my product listing. However **I want it to show only 2 columns and 1 row of products and have the special effect like below**. I don't know how I have to execute it :(.

[image]

Ask for any help from everyone. Thanks very much

Comment: if l:WrapLayout is your custom view,you will find way to solve it It looks like you want show effect in first Row,And Second Row is static
In my views,I will Create two different layout,one for show effect and another for show static

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, my data is showing dynamic data. The problem how can I handle the effect for them?

Comment: Have you try find function of items switch in custom view,if it does not exist,I suggest you create a custom view that meets your needs,at least i was does.And dynamic data was not question,just do notification well

Comment: Looks like it's a `Flip effect` for the items. You can refer to this [similar thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/309761/flip-effect-in-xamarin-forms.html).